# Find a substring in Oracle SQL “after first _ (underscore) to start” and “second _ (underscore) to end” using REGEXP_SUBSTR or SUBSTR function

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, regexp-substr

**My Input pattern like:**

```
WITH data_tab AS (
  SELECT '1540_INPUTTER' user_name FROM  dual 
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAZZ25_UNKNOWN' FROM  dual
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAKIB17_OS_WIN10' FROM  dual
  )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(user_name,…………………….....) AS st_user_name from data_tab
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ST_USER_NAME
------------
INPUTTER
RAZZ25
RAKIB17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is

```
WITH data_tab AS (
    SELECT '1540_INPUTTER' user_name FROM  dual 
    UNION SELECT '1540_RAZZ25_UNKNOWN' FROM  dual
    UNION SELECT '1540_RAKIB17_OS_WIN10' FROM  dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(user_name,'_([^_]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) AS st_user_name 
FROM data_tab;
```

Comment: Good one ..answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to define the complete structure of the string
and extract the second group:

```
WITH data_tab AS (
  SELECT '1540_INPUTTER' user_name FROM  dual
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAZZ25_UNKNOWN' FROM  dual
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAKIB17_OS_WIN10' FROM  dual
  )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(user_name,'(\d{4}_)([A-Z0-9]+)(_)?(\w+)?',1,1,'i',2)
```

AS st_user_name
    FROM data_tab;

Comment: Do not assume facts not included in the requirement, just because you see them in the data. The OP said nothing about the first part, up to the first underscore, being exactly four digits. At the very least, before you do something like this ask the OP to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
WITH data_tab AS (
  SELECT '1540_INPUTTER' user_name FROM  dual 
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAZZ25_UNKNOWN' FROM  dual
  UNION SELECT '1540_RAKIB17_OS_WIN10' FROM  dual
  )
SELECT

case when INSTR(SUBSTR(user_name, INSTR(user_name, '_')+1, length(user_name)- INSTR(user_name, '_')+1 ),'_') =0 then

SUBSTR(user_name, INSTR(user_name, '_')+1, length(user_name)- INSTR(user_name, '_')+1 )

else

substr((SUBSTR(user_name, INSTR(user_name, '_')+1, length(user_name)- INSTR(user_name, '_')+1 )), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(user_name, INSTR(user_name, '_')+1, length(user_name)- INSTR(user_name, '_')+1 ),'_') -1)

end as user_name

from data_tab
```